# Is it a good practice to subclass a UIViewController's subclass?

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, subclassing

Say you have a 2 subclass of tableView controller.

They both have the same header and footer view on top of the bottom of the header. They both implement pull to refresh.

They both have some common features.

The only different is one is for displaying the whole businesses, the other is for displaying only businesses you bookmark.

It looks like they both need to have the same parent class and the different is resolved on the child class. The differences are minor anyway.

I suppose the parent has it's own XIB, the children has it's own XIB.

Hmm... How would that work out? With the exception of container UIViewController, each controller should view a fullview of content. So which view should we display? The child or the superClass? Should child view add it's superclass subview?

Anyone have ever tried that?

Any code sample on the web that use this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like, based on the business logic you explain, that everything is in common, except the list of data you're presenting.  You could expose a property on your `UITableViewController` subclass to set the business objects that your tableview presents:

```
@interface JTBusinessesTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *businesses;

@end
```

The code that instantiates this class would set the business objects:

```
JTBusinessesTableViewController *businessListings; //Instantiate from XIB or Storyboard
businessListings.businesses = [self bookmarkedBusinesses];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:businessListings animated:YES]
```

The code for displaying all businesses isn't going to be much different:

```
JTBusinessesTableViewController *businessListings; //Instantiate from XIB or Storyboard
businessListings.businesses = [self allBusinesses]; //  Here we assign all of them

[self.navigationController pushViewController:businessListings animated:YES]
```

You're just selectively giving this view controller, the business objects to display.

Comment: That's cool. +1. What about if I really want to go the subclassing route?